# file_put_contents inserting javascript " " destroy closing

Tags: javascript, php

How to put the js script in `file_put_content`:

```
$videonova_content = "
           var InitialScriptApi = "<script src ='http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>";
           var youtubeTitle = "Wordpress";
           var youtubeSource = "fH6B4S9ENY4";
           var youtubeControl = "1";
           var youtubeAutoplay = "0";
           var youtubeDisplay = 7;
             var youtubeForcegrab = '0';
             ";

       file_put_contents($file, $videonova_content);
```

The problem is when inserting the js.
 " " destroy the enclosing . How to solve this?? Inserting " '""' " how to encapsule??

Comment: Escape " with \ ? i.e. `var youtubeTitle = \"Wordpress\";` ?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Right. I mean, duh. How can anyone not know how to escape quotes? -shrugs- Some "developers"...

Comment: I did hesitate before answering this question, thinking that I might be missing something. I am still not sure what the question is really about.

Comment: If you put var InitialScriptApi = "<script src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>";

Comment: @D.Kasipovic You could make an answer explaining HEREDOC or NOWDOC - I'd upvote you for that ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I would like to create a js file inside the file is    var InitialScriptApi = "<script src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>"; but encapsulating is the problem

Comment: Answer below should explain what you need. You should really read up on strings in php, and strings in programming in general. PHP is no exception to most basic rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I your script would not even run in PHP, you would get and syntax error, so I do not really see how you could have tested your script.

Proper way to fix your current script as it is, would be something like:

```
$videonova_content = "
var InitialScriptApi = \"<script src ='http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>\";
var youtubeTitle = \"Wordpress\";
var youtubeSource = \"fH6B4S9ENY4\";
var youtubeControl = \"1\";
var youtubeAutoplay = \"0\";
var youtubeDisplay = 7;
var youtubeForcegrab = '0';
";

file_put_contents($file, $videonova_content);
```

For that, you could read more at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

However, better way would be to use HEREDOC or NOWDOC, since their purpose is exactly what you need. So, in your case, it would be something like this:

```
$videonova_content = <<<SCRIPT
var InitialScriptApi = "<script src ='http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>";
var youtubeTitle = "Wordpress";
var youtubeSource = "fH6B4S9ENY4";
var youtubeControl = "1";
var youtubeAutoplay = "0";
var youtubeDisplay = 7;
var youtubeForcegrab = '0';
SCRIPT;
file_put_contents($file, $videonova_content);
```

You can read more about HEREDOC at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I suggest the HEREDOC method as outlined in this answer.

Comment: It return 0 maybe the character i'm inserting to much??

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this because you can indent this unlike the HEREDOC method.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
var InitialScriptApi = "<script src ='http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>";
var youtubeTitle = "Wordpress";
var youtubeSource = "fH6B4S9ENY4";
var youtubeControl = "1";
var youtubeAutoplay = "0";
var youtubeDisplay = 7;
var youtubeForcegrab = '0';
<?   file_put_contents($file, ob_get_clean() ); ?>
```